# Unable to load .webp image using Glide in Android

Tags: android, android-glide, webp

I am using Glide v3.7.0 to load image. I have no problem in loading .png format. But I dont even receive error response while loading .webp. If I tried to load the same url in browser it getting downloaded as file. And the file can be open via Chrome display the image correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As currently `Glide` already provide support for `.webp` images.
Please check below open issue on Glide Github repo.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/571

Comment: It looks like webp is supported in glide based on the link you referenced.

Comment: I am using 3.7.0 glide, do we need to do something extra or webp format is loaded by default? my minimum sdk version is 5 & above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [GlideWebpDecoder](https://github.com/zjupure/GlideWebpDecoder)

This library is compatible with Glide version 4.+

And the author is always trying to support with newest version of Glide

This is the code snippet :

```
Transformation<Bitmap> circleCrop = new CircleCrop();
GlideApp.with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .optionalTransform(circleCrop)
    .optionalTransform(WebpDrawable.class, new WebpDrawableTransformation(circleCrop))
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Hey I stumbled upon this answer and I had a look at the sample app for the library. My use case is such that I do not have `circleCrop` or other transformations right now. How can I load `webp` images from server? For case like mine, the sample app does nothing (see line 103 of `ImageAdapter.java`), does it mean glide supports `webp` by default? It does not seem so for me. Can you help me in anyway?

Comment: Where is GlideApp Class or Object?? I can't find it.

Comment: @c-an you can see in https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3170 for more explanation about `GlideApp`